# what's wrong when I want to take it Exchange a refresh token for an ID token or access_token?

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth

Request :

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://securetoken.googleapis.com/v1/token?key=AIzaSyBtSpn3NQEztoJW5q7S6jSBeQSDlZ0gAEE");
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  $headers=array();
  $headers[]="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"grant_type = refresh_token & refresh_token =".$refresh_token);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($result == null) {
        continue;
    } else {
        return $result;
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Response :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [error] => stdClass Object
        (
            [code] => 403
            [message] => Requests from this Android client application <empty> are blocked.
            [status] => PERMISSION_DENIED
            [details] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [@type] => type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help
                            [links] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [description] => Google developer console API key
                                            [url] => https://console.developers.google.com/project/1087008891043/apiui/credential
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Welcome. Is that your actual key in that URL for everyone to see? Can you please share some more info on what you are trying to do and maybe what doesn't work instead of just pasting code here? Thanks

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then add a clearer description of your issue into your question. The title should not be the only text you provide!